# Confused about getting values from object in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, api

So I'm currently messing around with the Amazon API.

```
amazon = AmazonAPI('mykey', 'mykey', 'bmykey')

products = amazon.search(SearchIndex='Beauty',
                         ResponseGroup='ItemAttributes,OfferFull,OfferListings,Offers,SalesRank,OfferSummary',
                         Sort='salesrank', BrowseNode='3777891')
```

Im trying to save the certain parts of the result into a database

type returned

```
<class 'amazon.api.AmazonSearch'>
```

when I run this

```
for p in products:
     print(p.asin)
```

The results look something like this

```
B004B8AZH0
B00XTAFYKY
B0014P8L9W
B00QZ67ODE
B00ARF42H0
B011YRJ31O
```

I'm trying to pass this result to the database.

Table fields-
(INT(11)) id
(VARCHAR(255)) ASIN

I cant seem to pass the results into the database for some reason. Heres what I tried

```
cur = db.cursor()

for p in products:
    print(p.asin)
    add = """INSERT INTO products(ASIN) VALUES(%s)"""
    cur.execute(add, p.asin)
    db.commit()

cur.close()
db.close()
```

but returns

```
query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Tried running `str(p.asin)` but I get the same error.

Tried this

cur.execute("INSERT INTO products (ASIN) VALUES (%s)" % p.asin)

but I get

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'B004B8AZH0' in 'field list'")
```

Any other tips to try? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Did my answer help? If yes, please accept it if no, tell me

Answer (score 0):

The `cursor.execute` method you are looking for takes two arguments:

1. The query string with placeholders (`%s`). Don't use quotes around the placeholder.
2. An **iterable** of the values to use instead of the placeholders.

You were passing a string which means that `execute` tries to use every character of the string as a value. So simply put your argument inside a list:

```
cur.execute(your_query, [p.asin])
```

if you do the formatting yourself you introduce sql injection vulnerabilities.